# Simple calling method in java

Tags: java, methods, return, calling-convention

I'm generally trying to learn about calling methods and wondering why this simple exercise doesn't working.. (also interested in knowing if I can assign a generated int to a char(acter)at the end of it all)

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int y = makeMove(int x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static makeMove(int x) {
        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("please enter a number 1-9 " + i);
            i = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (i < 0 || i > 9) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid selection. Please Re-enter: ");
            }
        } while (i < 0 || i > 9);

        return i;
        int x = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont specify the parameter type in the method invocation, only in the signature. Also your makeMove method requires a return type in its signature. And yes, char and ints are interchangeable in java.

Comment: 1>u did not declare x 2>y = makeMove(x); it should not be y = makeMove(int x); 3>return should be last statement. U have written int x = i; after return i; which is incorrect 4>u declared x twice. which is not allowed.5>It should be public static int makeMove(int x) u missed the return type int in method signature 6> } brace is missing in main method

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare a variable inside a function call

```
public static void main (String args[]) {   

int y;

y = makeMove(int x);

System.out.println(y);
```

You need to pass in an integer value into makeMove. 
so..

```
y= makeMove(0);
```

or

```
int x=0;
y=makeMove(x);
```

Also to convert from Integer to Character you could use...

```
String conversion;
conversion = Integer.toString(42);
```

The string variable is not  a character variable, but it gets you half way there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up your brackets and some other syntax. You're trying to define a function within main. You can't do that. Also you shouldn't pass x since you never use it. Let's go step-by-step through.

```
public static makeMove(int x) {
```

You only ever use it after the return statement, which isn't allowed since you'll never execute anything after the return statement. You should change the function to

```
public static makeMove() {
```

Next let's look at your while loop

```
do
{
    System.out.print("please enter a number 1-9 " + i);
    i = keyboard.nextInt();  
    if (i < 0 || i > 9 ) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid selection. Please Re-enter: ");    
    }
}
while (i < 0 || i > 9 );
```

From the logic it seems like you want to accept 0-9. I would change this to

```
do
{
    System.out.print("please enter a number 0-9 ");
    i = keyboard.nextInt();  
    if (i < 0 || i > 9 ) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid selection. Please Re-enter: ");    
    }
}
while (i < 0 || i > 9 );
```

And from what I mentioned before, you should remove the assignment to x after the return

```
return i;
```

}

So the final code would look like:

```
import java.lang.System.*;

public class Run {  

    public static int makeMove() {  

        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("please enter a number 0-9 ");
            i = keyboard.nextInt();  
            if (i < 0 || i > 9 ) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid selection. Please Re-enter: ");    
            }
        }
        while (i < 0 || i > 9 );

        return i;

    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {   

        int y;

        y = makeMove();

        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```